# how to do login & log out in same page?

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, logout

> index.php

```
<div id="top_right_section">
    <div id="head_icon">
        <ul class="top">
            <li class="hover"><a href="#" onClick="revealModal('modalPage')">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="registration.php" class="about">Registration</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> login.php

```
 <?php session_start();
 ob_start();
 //Include database connection details
 require_once('config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

 //Validation error flag
 $errflag = false;

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
$str = @trim($str);
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$str = stripslashes($str);
}
return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
 $username=$_POST['fname'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

//Input Validations
if($username == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
$errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
$errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
$_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
session_write_close();
header("location:index.php");
exit();
}

//Create query
$qry=("SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE password='$pass' AND fname='$user'") or   die("Couldn't query the user-database.");
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
//Login Successful
$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['uid'];
$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['user_name'];
$_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
session_write_close();
header("location:index.php");
exit();
}else {

?>
```

> logout.php

```
<?php session_start();
 session_destroy();
 location .......
?>
```

I ve given a light box in the onclick event to login.. i want , if an user is login through that box, he/should redirect to the same index page, & i can do my coding to display his/her name with that,  login word should hide and in that place i want to put a log out button.. is dat possibel to do in a same page ????

Comment: Show the modal part of the code

Comment: i ve tried session with another pages.. but now i want to do in a same page..

Comment: @sarmistha where are you stuck?

Comment: WAIT I M TRYING YOUR CODE

Comment: @sarmistha If you think that my answer is helpful then mark it as accepted. thanks. And please talk to me I want to tell you, why?

Comment: no, der is no result... i m confused ... @BrokenHeartღ

Comment: @sarmistha where are you confused dear let me know. I will solve it.

Comment: ll u ?? really ?? @BrokenHeartღ

Comment: @sarmistha yes I will but you need to listen to me.

Answer (score 4):

At the time of login start the session by using the:

session_start();

Then use this:

```
<div id="top_right_section">
    <div id="head_icon">
        <ul class="top">
           <?php if(!isset($_SESSION)) { ?>
            <li class="hover"><a href="#" onClick="revealModal('modalPage')">Login</a>
            </li>
             <?php } else {?>
            <li class="hover"><a href="#">Logout</a>
            </li>
             <?php } ?>
            <li><a href="registration.php" class="about">Registration</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where you are using the query to check the credential use the session if the credentials are correct.

And at the time of logout destroy the session by using the `session_destroy();` .

Comment: how can i destroy my session after clicking the log out button ??

Comment: @sarmistha ji just redirect the page on another page where you need to write `session.destroy();` and after that again redirect the page on `index.php` page. ohk

Answer (score 2):

Of course. You can just set a `$_SESSION[]` variable and destroy the session if the user logs out. If the session variable is set, then you can show content which should only be shown to logged in users.

You can take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) for more information.

EDIT: Example:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        //Here Logout button
        //If the button is clicked just do session_destroy() to unset $_SESSION variables
    } else {
        //Here Login Form
        //If login correctly then set $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    }
?>
```

Comment: i ve already tried session ... but can i do both my login n logout in the same page ??

Comment: just tell me how to use the session destroy ?

Comment: Just call the function session_destroy() and the session get's destroyed.

Comment: If you call logout.php then the session should be destroyed.

Comment: is der anything should i change in my login.php page ??

Comment: Well, in your query you use $pass and $user instead of $password and $username and you don't use your clean() function.

Comment: let me try 4 another tym @marcel

Answer (score 2):

Yeah its quite simple..

All you will do to login will be seting up a session variable to get the user details(say the primary key of the table)

Check like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    Logout and so so on what you want
}else{
    Login goes here
}
```